# Exactly one ring homomorphism $F[X] \rightarrow S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and $f \in F[X]/(f)$. Let $f$ have a zero point $\alpha$, that is, $f(\alpha)=0$. Let $F$ be a subring of $S$, and $\beta \in S$ with $f(\beta)=0$. Show that there is exactly one ring homomorphism $\phi: F[\alpha] \rightarrow S$, with $\alpha\phi=\beta$ and $\phi |_{F}=id_F$.
How do I begin this question? Thanks.

Comment: Show that the two properties you are given completely determine $\phi$. In other words, there is only one possible value for $\phi(x)$, for all $x\in F[\alpha]$.

Comment: I assume that you mean $f \in F[X]$, and $\phi(\alpha) = \beta$.

Comment: Yes. $\alpha \phi=\phi(\alpha)$
Why is only one possible value $\phi (x)$. I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the universal property of (a) polynomial rings, (b) quotient rings.